# How do I remove two smallest numbers from a numpy array and calculate median python 3

Tags: python, numpy

I am generating a 5x3 random array. I need to identify and remove the smallest two numbers and then calculate the median with rest of the numbers. I am able to identify the smallest number, but unable to proceed further.

```
import numpy as Np

a = Np.random.randint(100, size = (5,3))
print(a)
print('\n')

sort1 = Np.concatenate(a, axis=0)
print("Concatenated: ", sort1)
print('\n')
sort2 = Np.sort(sort1)
print(sort2)
print('\n')

c = Np.min(sort2,0) #min
print(c)
print('\n')

med = Np.median(sort2)
print("Median is: ", med)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a = Np.random.randint(100, size = (5,3))
a = Np.delete(a, a.argmin())
a = Np.delete(a, a.argmin())
Np.median(a)

# 48.0
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! Your code is amazing. I had tried delete, remove, pop...but not argmin with it... Thank you again for taking some time and providing an input

Answer (score 0):

Well, you managed to get the smallest number, now you need to remove it.

I would create a list, you don't actually need an array to calculate the median. 
After creating the list it gets easier, you remove the items with list.remove() and the median function stays the same.

Your code will look like this:

```
import numpy as Np

a = Np.random.randint(100, size = (5,3))


sort1 = list(Np.concatenate(a, axis=0))

sort1.remove(min(sort1))

med = Np.median(sort1)

sort1.remove(min(sort1))

med2 = Np.median(sort1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It is really helping to see different ways to code ...